# Read source path from a registry on compile time in Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

Reading a registry value from the `[Code]` section is quite easy.
But if I have to read the value of a registry (an installation path) to be used in the `[Files]` section in order to copy files from a source folder the the install/destination folder

I tried:

```
Source: "{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyApp,InstallDir|DefaultDirName}\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\Mydestination"; AfterInstall: AfterInstallProc
```

receiving the error

> "unknown filename prefix 'reg:'".

Or is there a possibility to read a registry value at the beginning and storing it (a constant? and variable?) in order to be used in the `[Files]` section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documentation says](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection), you can use constants only when you use an `external` flag:

> Constants may only be used when the `external` flag is specified, because the compiler does not do any constant translating itself.

It's because the constants are resolved on run-time, while the (non-external) files are compiled into the installer on compile time.

If you want to read the registry on the target machine, you actually want to use the `external` flag anyway.

---

If you want to read local registry, use [pre-processor function `ReadReg`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=readreg):

```
Source: "{#ReadReg(HKLM, "SOFTWARE\MyApp", "InstallDir", "DefaultDirName")}\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\Mydestination"; AfterInstall: AfterInstallProc
```

---

Though I'd personally prefer a value set on the command-line of the compiler:

```
Source: "{#InstallDir}\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Mydestination"; \
    AfterInstall: AfterInstallProc
```

Set as:

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DInstallDir=c:\path
```