# Inno Setup ReadReg run-time target program folder, add WAR file to tomcat/webapps

Tags: xampp, registry, inno-setup, war

I would like to save a WAR file to `xampp\tomcat\webapps` by using Inno Setup's `ReadReg` functionality to find the `Install_Dir` for XAMPP. This question is similar to [Inno Setup: read source path from a registry on compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348414/inno-setup-read-source-path-from-a-registry-on-compile-time) but I think the answer I need is flip-flopped. Here's what I have:

```
Source: "D:\Content.war"; \
  DestDir: "{#ReadReg(HKLM, "SOFTWARE\xampp", "Install_Dir", "DefaultDirName")}\tomcat\webapps"; \
  Flags: ignoreversion
```

But it doesn't save the WAR file to the target computer's XAMPP folder. Please let me know how this should be properly structured/coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) and [`RegQueryStringValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue):

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\Content.war"; DestDir: "{code:GetXamppPath}\tomcat\webapps"
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetXamppPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\xampp', 'Install_Dir', Result);
end;
```

Though you should also add some error handling (particularly in case there's no such registry key).

---

*Btw, the [answer that you have based your script on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33348414/850848#33348581) is correct. But it does, what the other question asks for: it reads the key on compile-time = on the machine, where it is built on. That's not what you want.*